# Angular return [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to send a post request. But the API returns undefined, and I send it to my API, as it turned out [object Object]

```
getAccouting():Observable<any>{
    // let json = this.http.get<any>('/assets/cities/altayskiy_kray/accounting.json'); if i use it json return undefined
    let json;
    this.http.get('/assets/cities/altayskiy_kray/accounting.json').pipe(data=>json=data);
    let formData:FormData = new FormData;
    formData.append('json', json);
    return this.http.post<any>('http://api/api.php', formData);
  }
```

How fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending two HTTP Requests one after each other using Angular / RXJS where second request requires the first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828453/sending-two-http-requests-one-after-each-other-using-angular-rxjs-where-second)

Comment: See the second answer for how to use a pipe `this.http.get().pipe(
      mergeMap(response: Response => this.http.get(response.doSomething())
    )`. The docs for `switchMap()` operator are a good starting point too https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: Christoph, no it is not answer, that not work :(

Comment: "does not work" will not help to provide you a better answer. The linked answer shows the basics of how to do two async http calls and you really need to understand the basics. Assuming you now know how to do multiple http calls, how does your code looks like now and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: If i use this.http.get(), then get the error "an argument for the uri was expected". 
And if I add, as indicated above, then where mergeMap throws the error: "Type argument"(json: ArrayBuffer) => void" cannot be assigned to a type parameter "(value: ArrayBuffer, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>".
The type "void" cannot be assigned to the type "Observable Input<any>".ts(2345)", 
but besides I wrote "mergeMap(json=>"

Comment: And if write "response: Response =>", it gives the error "The name "response" cannot be found. Did you mean "Response"?ts(2552)
lib.dom.d.ts(11146, 13): "Response" is declared here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.get` is async so it will not have emitted before you return the `http.post`. Therefore, `json` will be undefined.

Instead you can chain them and return the whole observable:

```js
getAccouting(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('/assets/cities/altayskiy_kray/accounting.json').pipe(
    switchMap(json => {
      return this.http.post<any>('http://api/api.php', json);
    }
  );
}
```

Do you need to use `FormData`? If you append the `json` object then you will get its string value: `[object Object]`.

You could stringify the `json` object, but you will have to decode it on the server:

```
formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(json))
```

Comment: For some reason, I now need the json variable in FormData.append('json', json);

Comment: Do you need to use `FormData`?

Comment: I do not know, but without it, the request is not sent

Comment: So you could append each key-value from the `json` object to the `FormData`. Or you could use `formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(json))` but then you'd have to decode it on the other end.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it solved your issue :)